# Простейший пример Java-аннотации для создания цепных сеттеров

Tags: java

Прочитал статей 5 о Java аннотациях - так и не понял механизм их работы. Многие примеры слишком далеки от того, что бывает на практике.

Задача этого вопроса - предоставить начинающим Java-программистам (в том числе и мне) простой, но при этом применимый на практике пример.

```
class Person {

  String familyName;
  String givenName;

  Person setFamilyName(String value) {
    this.familyName = value;
    return this;
  }

  Person getGivenName(String value) {
    this.givenName= value;
    return this;
  }
}
```

Как, используя аннотации, достичь такого синтаксиса:

```
class Person {
  @ProvideChainalbeSetter
  String familyName;
  @ProvideChainalbeSetter
  String givenName;
}
```

Пока я только знаю, что у аннотации будет `@Target(ElementType.FIELD)`.

P. S.: про Lombok знаю.

Comment: Опишите словами, что в итоге вы хотите получить. Чтобы в runtime-е создавались геттеры/сеттеры и возвращался объект?

Comment: тут не все так просто. на этапе компиляции ваша аннотация должна обрабатываться и уже изменять байткод, вставляя туда нужные сеттеры

Comment: в lomblok есть прекрасная аннотация `@Builder`, (паттерн строитель).  Позволяет использовать похожий синтаксис `Person.builder().familyName("name").givenName("name2").build()`, можно использовать над конструктором (сузить количество полей, как пример). Чем он не подходит для задачи из вопроса? Метод `getGivenName` должен быть сеттером или возвращать строку, а не объект.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Такое впечатление, что вы пробуете применить к аннотациям Java семантику аннотации Python.

В Python аннотации `@smth` аналогичны старым добрым `advices` из Lisp, когда код модифицируется на лету. То есть когда в Python написано

```
@smth
def f():
    pass
```

то вызывается функция `smth`, которая обрабатывает функциональный объект, который транслятор сделал для тела `f`, и результат этого вызова сохраняется в имени f. Налицо глубокая интеграция транслятора и среды выполнения.

В Java аннотации устроены совсем иначе. Это действительно аннотации, то есть флаги, которые прикрепляются к классам, методам, полям и параметрам, и которые можно извлечь через reflection во время выполнения.

## Рассуждение об аннотациях в Java

Главный кейс для аннотаций в Java - разработка фреймворков. Например, вы задумали сделать фреймворк для тестирования. Пусть пользователи передают в тест-раннер классы, содержащие тестовые методы. Задача фреймворка найти в этих классах тестовые методы, вызвать их и запротоколировать результаты вызова.

Как ваш фреймворк отличит в классе тестовые методы от обычных, вспомогательных? Простейший способ через соглашение о наименовании. Например, все тестовые методы должны называться `test_XXX`. Но через аннотации можно сделать красивше. И гибчее. Например, потребовать, чтобы все тестовые методы были помечены `@Test`, а методы для инициализации и зачистки состояния помечены как `@Before` и `@After`.

Дальше просто. Тестовый раннер должен пробежаться по списку методов класса, найти методы с аннотациями `org.example.test.Test`, `org.example.test.Before`, `org.example.test.After`, создать объект целевого класса, и далее для этого объекта в цикле:

```
    для каждого M с аннотацией Test {
        вызывать методы с аннотацией Before
        вызвать M
        вызвать методы с аннотацией After
    }
```

Примеров такого использования аннотаций вагон и маленькая тележка. Все современные фреймворки так или иначе используют аннотации. Именно для того, чтобы во время выполнения найти методы со специальной семантикой и специальным образом их обработать.

## Если хочется как в Python

Но если хочется пользоваться аннотациями так, как в Python - то есть для изменения семантики без всяких фреймворков, то нужно залезть в компилятор `javac` и заняться темномагическим шаманством.

Сразу скажу, что я знаю только общие принципы и видел однажды человека, который это умел делать, но сам не умею.

Если вы хотите сделать геттеры и сеттеры для полей, помеченных аннотациями, то

1. Вам нужно создать плагин для компилятора `javac`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/util/Plugin.html
2. В плагине реализовать обработчик событий компилятора: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/util/TaskEvent.html
3. Для вашей задачи нужно сделать обработчик для события `PARSE`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/util/TaskEvent.Kind.html
   В этом обработчике в методе `finished` нужно найти узел, соответствующий объявлению класса, в нём найти узлы декларации полей с вашими аннотациями, и если такие поля найдены, то ...
4. Создать для них новые узлы в AST для геттеров и сеттеров (ИМХО, **самая чёрная магия** Java)
   В Java нет методов для парсинга строки и генерации из этой строки дерева AST. Поэтому дерево нужно будет создавать ручками, конструируя все необходимые узлы. Засада в том, что типы, представляющие узлы в дереве, недокументированы. И фактически придётся подбирать правильные цепочки узлов методом тыка.

Для типов узлов есть интерфейсы из [`com.sun.source.tree`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/index.html), но реализации этого интерфейса недокументированы. Известно, что компиляторы javac вплоть до нынешнего времени пользуются для представления узлов вложенными классами недокументированного класса `com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree`

Например, узел, представляющий метод, должен быть объектом класса `com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl`, реализующего интерфейс [`com.sun.source.tree.MethodTree`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/tree/MethodTree.html), у которого есть дети для представления параметров, типа возвращаемого результата, модификаторов доступа и тела.

5. Узлы для дерева конструируются через вызовы соответствующих методов в недокументированном классе `com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker`

Вот, как-то так. Не уверен, что на ваш вопрос возможен "простой, но при этом применимый на практике пример", тем более понятный начинающим программистам на Java.

### План Б - замена загрузчика

Можно пошаманить с настройками и подсунуть системе свой кастомный загрузчик, который будет в процессе загрузки модифицировать байт-код и внедрять в загружаемые классы байт-код для геттеров и сеттеров. Имхо, это лишь немногим проще, и тоже не подходит для "начинающих программистов Java" :)

## Обработка аннотаций в Lombok

Lombok обрабатывает аннотации для геттеров и сеттеров именно так, как я написал выше. У них разработана навороченная инфраструктура, но в конечном итоге всё сводится к добавлению узлов в дерево синтаксического разбора.

Генератор кода для аннотации `@Getter`: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/javac/handlers/HandleGetter.java#L170

Генератор кода для аннотации `@Setter`: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/javac/handlers/HandleSetter.java#L204

## Ресурсы для изучения

Как оказалось, в интернетах полно тюториалов про аннотации, но они какие-то бестолковые. Перечисляют стандартные аннотации, в лучшем случае описывают синтаксис для кастомных аннотаций.

На первых нескольких страницах выдачи гугла нашел всего несколько стоящих примеров:

1. [Короткий тюториал](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAnnotations/article.html), который тем не менее, раскрывает концепцию использования аннотации для создания всевозможных раннеров в разделе 3.
2. [Тьюториал по созданию JSON сериализатора](https://www.juvo.be/blog/creating-annotations-java). Показывает пример прикрепления аннотаций к полям.
3. [Длинная запутанная статья](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101), в которой аннотации используются для генерации кода. Там не Lombok, а сценарий попроще, в котором генерируются целые классы по описанию в аннотациях. Пример сомнительной ценности, ИМХО, но на безрыбье...
4. [Статья о подводных камнях аннотаций](https://blog.softwaremill.com/the-case-against-annotations-4b2fb170ed67). Если коротко, то в некоторых фреймворках аннотации используются для ссылок на внешние ресурсы, которые нужно обработать перед выполнением целевого метода. Такой сценарий создаёт массу проблем, поскольку нет гарантий, что в рантайме такой ресурс доступен, а также это создаёт нетривиальную зависимость, которую нужно где-то документировать и потом отслеживать.

Для начального уровня тюториалы 1 и 2 самое то. Чтобы продвинуться дальше нужно будет написать свой фреймворк с аннотациями, набив свои собственные шишки.

Comment: Уточнение: в Питоне описанная конструкция называется и является декоратором, а не аннотацией.

Comment: @AivanF, спасибо. Конечно, декораторы.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за подробный ответ! Понял, буду изучать этот вопрос...

Comment: @БоковГлеб, прошу прощения, только сейчас посмотрел, что пишут в интернете про аннотации. Действительно, преимущественно какой-то шлак от индийских "гуру программирования". Добавил раздел со ссылками на несколько стоящих тюториалов по аннотациям, которые нашлись на первых страницах выдачи гугла.

Comment: Ничего страшного, я Вам очень благодарен, что вы поделились этими ссылками.

Answer (score 1):

По сути в Java Getter Setter это обертка некоего поля. Если вам так хочется изменять его напрямую то откройте поле в паблик. Генерацию всех геттеров и сетторов все популярные IDE имею в коробке. Ведь идея Getter Setter не только изменять или скрывать поля, а производить дополнительные манипуляции с объектом или чего ещё если надо хотя бы элементарное логирование.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Цель этого вопроса - не решить, как лучше изменять геттеры и сеттеры, а привести пример аннотации, чтобы понять, как они работают. "Если вам так хочется изменять его напрямую то откройте поле в паблик." - Не то, что бы "этого категорически нельзя делать в ООП", но а смысл тогда в инкапсуляции. "Генерацию всех геттеров и сеттеров все популярные IDE имею в коробке." - если добавление геттеров и сеттеров через аннотацию настолько бессмысленно, то зачем в Lombok реализован такой функционал?

Comment: не путайте инкапсуляцию с сокрытием данных. ИН КАПСУЛА - достаточно чтоб они были в капсуле, а сокрытие реализуется механизмами инкапсуляции. Зачем Lombok реализовал этот функционал? Думаю вопрос не по адресу. Добавление геттеров и сеттеров через аннотацию - "Стрелять из пушки по воробьям".